# I am using ISP Config host, I just updated shopware 6.4.20 to 6.5.6 and dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"

Tags: php, server, e-commerce, shopware, shopware6

I am using ISP Config host, I just updated shopware 6.4.20 to 6.5.6, for which I had to change the php version so I changed it from host settings and it was shown in admin that its updated, but now bin/console not working, and says

"Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.13.

PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.13. in /web/dev/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24"

I tried the composer update its showing 5 problems that dependencies also require PHP8.1 but the current is 7.4.13

Comment: You need to update your php version then

Comment: it was already updated .

Comment: Presumablt the CLI version wasn't updated though, as per the answer you've marked as accepted, below

Comment: yes its not updated but you will be able to use the bin/console using the updated php path .  but if you want to update the cli version of php you can also do it using .profile file in the root .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your CLI version of PHP is still PHP 7.4, whilst the ISP has updated only the web server's version to PHP 8.1.

Check your CLI PHP version by running `php -v` from the CLI.

If it is still 7.4, you may want your provider to either change it, or ask him  for the specific php command to use another version. (Note on many systems this could just be `/usr/bin/php8.1` instead of `php`.)